# Tengo un checkbox llamado c, quiero que cuando esté verificado me ejecute el primer condicional y cuando no el segundo

Tags: java, java-swing

```
`
```

> Checkbox

```
            JCheckBox c = new JCheckBox();//checkbox
            c.setFocusable(false);
            c.setOpaque(true);
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.setLayout(null);
            f.add(l);
            f.add(l1);
            f.add(c);
```

> Evento para verificar si el checkbox esta marcado
> c.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

```
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
```

> Primer condicional
> if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {

```
                        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
    
                                calculadora.setOperador1(Integer.parseInt(b.getText()));
    
                                l.setText(String.valueOf(calculadora.getOperador1()));
    
                            }
                        });
   
                    }
```

> Segundo condicional
> if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {//

```
                        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
                                calculadora.setOperador2(Integer.parseInt(b1.getText()));
    
                                l1.setText(String.valueOf(calculadora.getOperador2()));
    
                            }
                        });
                       
                    };
                }
            });
```

> **Al marcar por primera vez el checkbox, se ejecuta el primer condicional, pero cuando lo desmarco se ejecutan los dos condicionales al mismo tiempo**

Comment: Podrias por favor [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/550823/edit) la pregunta y formatearla correctamente, resulta confuso de entender.. nose que parte es codigo, en que parte hablas tu etc..

Answer (score 0):

Deberias usar el metodo 'isSelected' de JCheckBox:

```
JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox("Mi Checkbox");

// Chequea el estado del JCheckbox
if (checkbox.isSelected()) {
  // Esta seleccionado, ejecuta el primer condicional 
  ...
} else {
  // sino, ejecuta el segundo
  ...
}
```